# How do I use substring in WHERE clause?

Tags: abap, opensql

My expression in OpenSQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM  J_1BNFLIN  AS B
  WHERE SUBSTRING(REFKEY , 1 , 10 )
```

The substring portion of the where clause is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As fas as I know, there is no SUBSTRING in OpenSQL. What do you want exactly? You want the first ten characters of field REFKEY from table J_1BNFLIN?

Comment: Yes @JozsefSzikszai

Comment: Sorry, I might misunderstood the problem, so I ask again: You want to use the first 10 characters of field REFKEY as a selection criteria?

Comment: Yes, with possibilty of SUBSTRING(REFKEY , 1 , 10 )  = SUBSTRING(REFKEY , 4 , 4 )

Comment: No, there is no such possibility. There is no `SUBSTRING` in OpenSQL and [substring access](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenoffset_length.htm) also doesn't work for the left side operands (but works for right). Jozsef is right, your only solution is LIKE.

Comment: SUBSTRING is accepted from ABAP 7.50, on the left side of a condition. References: [release changes 7.50 - new SQL functions](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abennews-750-open_sql.htm#!ABAP_MODIFICATION_5@5@)

Comment: Yep, you are right! My info is outdated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LIKE in the WHERE condition. For example:

```
DATA: gv_refkey TYPE j_1bnflin-refkey.
gv_refkey = '123%'.
SELECT *
       INTO TABLE ...
       FROM j_1bnflin
       WHERE refkey LIKE gv_refkey.
```

This will select all entries where the field refkey starts with '123' (pls. note a % is used as wildcard)

Comment: Thanks everybody ,but in special  JozsefSzikszai and Suncatcher