# OpenSQL offset in WHERE clause

Tags: abap, opensql

I have this requirement: There is a field of 8-byte length and I want to extract the last 4 bytes using SQL.

Example: There is date `01012017` so I want only `2017`. How can I achieve this using `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What tables? What fields?

Comment: use `WHERE date = lv_date+4(4)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use substring in OpenSQL ABAP WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885655/how-do-i-use-substring-in-opensql-abap-where-clause)

Comment: What's wrong with the LIKE clause?

Answer (score 0):

You should select the data in full flesh, then use

```
LOOP AS it_fulldate ASSIGNING <ls_fulldate>.
  <ls_fulldate>-date = <ls_fulldate>-date+4(4).
ENDLOOP.
```

But usually, date time data type is YYYYMMDD so the correct might be `<ls_fulldate>-date+0(4)`